# Reset Border style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a image that is currently being styled with Jquery once it's clicked. I eventually hide it in Javascript. I want to reshow it, but I want it to have the border removed.

Here is HTML:

```
<div id="playOptionsWager" style="display: none">
    <h4>Choose your move to beat the computer!</h4>
    <img id="clickedRockWager" src="img/rock.jpg" onclick="playWagerRock()" />
    <img id="clickedPaperWager" src="img/paper.jpg" onclick="playWagerPaper()"/>
    <img id="clickedScissorsWager" src="img/scissors.jpg" onclick="playWagerScissors()" />
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(function () {
    $("img").on("click",function() {
        $(this).siblings().css('border','0px')
        $(this).css('border', "solid 2px red");
    });
});
```

Here is what I was trying in Javascript:

```
function autobet() {
    coinBalance -= currentBet*2;
    alert(getBalance());
    document.getElementsByTagName("IMG").style.border="";
}
```

However when it reshows the div it has the border on it still.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Can you please make a working example of this?

Comment: Are you definitely calling the `autobet` function?

Comment: yes I'm calling autobet I get error "Cannot set property 'border' of undefined"

Comment: can you make a fiddle?

Comment: but tagname will return a array of elements

Comment: @Jona Are you using a stylesheet? One of the issues that hasn't been addressed yet in the answers is how `...style.border = "";` is affected by a stylesheet. It removes the _inline_ style, that is, from the style attribute on the <img> tag. So if the border originally was in the style attribute, this works, but if the original border was defined in the stylesheet, not.

Comment: The difference with `...style.border = 0;` is that the latter does not remove the style, rather it _changes_ it, thus overriding any value in the stylesheet.

Answer (score 2):

Your issue is that `document.getElementsByTagName("IMG")` returns a collection of elements, so simply applying `.style.border` on this collection won't work. Instead, you need to loop over this collection, and set every image within it to have no border using `.style.border = 0;`:

See working example (with div) below:

```js
function removeBorder() {
  [...document.getElementsByTagName("div")].forEach(elem => {
    elem.style.border = 0;
  });
}
```

```css
.box {
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  background: black;
  display: inline-block;
}

.active {
  border: 3px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
<div class="box active"></div>
<div class="box"></div>

<br />
<button onclick="removeBorder()">Remove border</button>
```

Also note that `[...document.getElementsByTagName("IMG")]` is a way of converting the collection of elements into an array of elements, which thus allows us to use the `.forEach` method to loop over it.

Answer (score 0):

You started with jQuery, let's continue with jQuery.

```
function autobet() {
    coinBalance -= currentBet*2;
    alert(getBalance());
    $("img").css("border","");
}
```

The problem is that `getElementsByTagName()` returns a collection not one element.

Comment: that doesn't appear to be working either. No errors tho.

Answer (score -1):

First you need to iterate over the collection of html elements you have - when using getElementsByTagName you get back an array of elements.
Second you need to give the elements a style of zero.

```
const divElements = document.getElementsByTagName("IMG");
for (let i=0; i < divElements.length; i++) {
  divElements[i].style.border = 0;
}
```

You can see the code on stackbliz - 
https://stackblitz.com/edit/border-issue?file=index.js

Comment: Cannot set property 'border' of undefined same error with yours. even added in "0"

Comment: i missed that you has more than one element, now the answer works for you.